# split a string and use each item to assign to another list

Tags: c#

I have a list of roles to assign to users:

```
var role1 = new Role { ApplicationName = "XXX", RoleName = "ROLE1" };
var role2 = new Role { ApplicationName = "XXX", RoleName = "ROLE2" };
var role3 = new Role { ApplicationName = "XXX", RoleName = "ROLE3" };

List<Role> listRoles = new List<Role>
{
    role1,
    role2,
    role3
};
```

I can assign a specific role like this:

```
var userRoles = new List<Role> 
{
    listRoles.First(x => x.RoleName == "ROLE1")
}
```

Let's say I have a string with listed roles to add to my user

```
string listRoles = "ROLE1;ROLE3";
```

My question: how can I assign a list of roles to my user?

I try:

```
var userRoles = new List<Role> 
{
    foreach(var role in listRoles.Split(";")
    {
        listRoles.First(x => x.RoleName == role);
    }
}
```

I got compile error.

Comment: And what was that compile error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use foreach loop inside the [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), you can't do that. Instead you can do the following:

```
var userRoles = new List<Roles>();

foreach(var role in listRoles.Split(";"))
{
   userRoles.Add(listRoles.First(x => x.RoleName == role))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have compilation error because you use the same variable name `listRoles` for both string and list of origina roles.

```
var rolesToAssign = "ROLE1;ROLE3";
var matchingRoles = rolesToAssign.Split(';');

var userRoles = listRoles.Where(x => matchingRoles.Contains(x.RoleName))
                         .ToList();
```